# Taking Advantage of Allah’s mercy

Tags: practical-islam, allah, forgiveness, blessings-of-allah, fear

I’ve watched videos and videos of Islamic motivational videos talking about how merciful Allah is to the sinner. But the thing is, it’s made me feel really guilty and vulnerable. Because I’ve began to think that it’s okay for me to sin because I know Allah will forgive me, and it’s made me lose the fear of Allah I need as a believer. To put it in different words, I feel like I’m taking advantage of Allah’s mercy.

- How can I get this fear of Allah back?
- How can I change my mentality to not sin as shamelessly?
- Would Allah stop forgiving me because of this?

**Note:** I still cry and feel remorse when I repent. 
**Note:** I don’t shamelessly go around sinning, I still try my best to be a good Muslim and refrain from what’s been told to be haram.

Comment: Don't worry Allah will forgive you because you are trying to be a good muslim and allah sees how a person is doing his best to please allah

Answer (score 0):

The Quran does not ground the path of the *believers* on fear. It warns the disbelievers.

The believer's path should be based on **deen**. This includes faith, true endeavours to act righteously and in concordance with the Will of God. The recommended path will lead through following the prescribed "excercises" (5 pillars) to a internalization of His Will. On this path you will not want to sin.

I think you are still on this path. Go on.

Comment: I definitely agree, however, as Muslims, isn’t it important to have fear of Allah? What can I do to get that fear back? I don’t want to come off as being arrogant towards Allah.

Comment: A rider can make a horse obey him from fear. A good rider makes the horse obeying through faith that the rider takes the best decision. Still he has to educate it first. This is how understand God

Answer (score 0):

By sinning you are just harming yourself, it can be psychological, physical, spiritual and so on. by doing sins you hardening your heart more.

> The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said,
> “Verily, when the servant commits a sin, a black mark appears upon his
> heart. If he abandons the sin, seeks forgiveness, and repents, then
> his heart will be polished. If he returns to the sin, the blackness
> will be increased until it overcomes his heart. It is the covering
> that Allah has mentioned: No, rather a covering is over their hearts
> from what they have earned.”

*Sunan al-Tirmidhī 3334*

The more harden your heart gets, the more it'll be difficult for you to avoid sinning.

> “I am Forgiving to those who repent and believe and do good, and
> **afterward follow right guidance.**”

*[Sūrah TāHā: 82]*

**Note that there is difference between a person who's trying his best to stay away from  sin but falling in sin even though he's trying, than a person who's thinking to sin for now and ask for forgiveness later.**

The person who is sinning and planed to ask forgiveness from Allah later on,  is only causing problems for himself.

So try your best to obey Allah. Instead of sinning and then planning to ask for his forgiveness later on.